# Logging not working in web application using Spring AOP

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, logging, spring-aop

using Spring AOP, I'm trying to put logging in my web application for an object called corelation like below :-

**LoggingCorrelationEnrichingAspect.java:-**

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingCorrelationEnrichingAspect {
    private static final Logger logger = getLogger(LoggingCorrelationEnrichingAspect.class);

    @Around("@annotation(Correlated)")
    public Object wrapWithCorrelationContext(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
            logger.info("Entering  "+ proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName() +" with Correlation Id:: "
                    + ((Map)proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs()[0]).get(CommerceConnectorConstants.HttpHeaders.CORRELATION_ID).get());
        return ((Mono<?>) proceedingJoinPoint.proceed());
    }
}
```

**Correlated.java:-**

```
@Inherited
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Correlated {}
```

In my main REST Controller operation, using `@Correlated` annotation, I'm trying to log this corellation like below :-

```
  @Correlated
  @GetMapping(path = "/products}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
  public Mono<ProductBeanResponse> getProducts(
      @RequestHeader(name = Test.HttpHeaders.TENANT_ID, required = true) UUID tId,
      @RequestHeader(name = Test.HttpHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, required = true) UUID correlationId
----
---
}
```

However, when I test my service using PostMan tool and see the applicaiton logs, the corelation id is never logged :-

```
logger.info("Entering  "+ proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName() +" with Correlation Id:: "
                    + ((Map)proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs()[0]).get(CommerceConnectorConstants.HttpHeaders.CORRELATION_ID).get());
```

Please advise is this a configuration issue in Spring AOP.

Thanks

Comment: The first method argument isn't a `Map` but a `UUID`. Also you shouldn't be casting to a `Mono` in your aspect you should just return the result of `proceedingJoinPoint.proceed()`.

Comment: thanks, i tried your suggestion but still now working. any idea

Comment: Is the aspect even being invoked? I actually doubt that as if it would be invoked your application would crash with a `ClassCastException` stating that a `UUID` cannot be cast to a `Map`.

Comment: not sure but i think it should invoke because i have annotated my method operation in Restcontroller using @Correlated.....please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can get working in either of below two ways

1. Provide fully qualified name of `Correlated` in the pointcut definition as `@Around("@annotation(com.x.y.z.Correlated)")`
2. Update the Aspect method signature to include the `Correlated` as second argument

   ```
   @Around("@annotation(correlated)")
   public Object wrapWithCorrelationContext(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, Correlated correlated ) throws Throwable {
       logger.info("Entering  "+ proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName() +" with Correlation Id:: "
               + ((Map)proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs()[0]).get(CommerceConnectorConstants.HttpHeaders.CORRELATION_ID).get());
   return ((Mono<?>) proceedingJoinPoint.proceed());
   }
   ```

Let know in comments if anything else is required.

**P.S.**: Also as pointed out by M. Deinum make sure to remove object cast.